# Upgrade Java version for Web Application

Tags: java

I have a web Application and  i need to upgrade java jre version from 6 to 7 .I am using Eclipse as IDE.I tried to update the Jre from eclipse .I have even updated the JAVA_HOME environment variable but i am getting following error

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\jre..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Thanks

Comment: What servlet container/API are you using? Do you need to upgrade that too?

Comment: Well that would be one thing to keep in mind: it MAY be that the container is not properly compatible with newer runtimes and needs to be upgraded too.

Answer (score 0):

Download java [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)and install it as a common application.
Then in Eclipse use **Window->Prefrences->Java->Installed JREs**

Comment: I did that but when I am trying to build ear its throwing error  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\jre\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Comment: Post exception trace here and let's discuss it.

Comment: I added the JDK version 7 in eclipse and updated the java_home environment variable  .Now i am getting following errorUnable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

@Roman Bondar I guesss OP wanted to know more than just the setting.

Basically, JREs are meant to be downwards compatible, so that you are able to execute java classes compiled with version 6 with a runtime from java 7.

But as always, there may be special cases when things have to be changed, e.g. container or libraries. I remember a case back when I migrated to java 6 that it required a special version of JBoss.

Check out [this Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/migrating_from_java_se_6) as a starting point.

Comment: Yeah there was a special version of JBoss 4.2.3 for Java 6. And it actually missed some libraries so the regular pre-Java 6 download worked a whole lot better under Java 6 :) JBoss has always been funny like that.

Comment: @ Gimby I am using JBoss 4.2.3 along with Java 6 .

Comment: @crazyStart Then it's about time to change - JBoss is currently at version 8, so you might want to upgrade the container, at least to version 6 if you want to keep more or less the old configuration.

Comment: Thanks for reply .Can you please help me with my updated Question

Comment: @crazyStart As your message says, you need a JDK, not a JRE. So in eclipse, add a Java Runtime by using a full JDK installation.